# Dimension reduction using Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have a data set of MNIST hand written digits with 257 columns.

```
1 : 256 - pixel values
257 - target
```

How do I design an auto encoder using keras to reduce the input using 2 dimensions.

What I have tried

```
encoding_dim = 32 
input_img = Input(shape=(256,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input=input_img, output=decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(X, X,
            nb_epoch=50,
            batch_size=256,
            shuffle=True)
```

Error

```
KeyError: '[318 327 ...] not in index
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keras autoencoder vs PCA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722259/keras-autoencoder-vs-pca)