# Keras autoencoder classification

Tags: keras, classification, autoencoder

I am trying to find a useful code for improve classification using autoencoder.
I followed this example [keras autoencoder vs PCA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722259/keras-autoencoder-vs-pca)
But not for MNIST data, I tried to use it with cifar-10

so I made some changes but it seems like something is not fitting.
Could any one please help me in this?
if you have another example that can run in different dataset, that would help.

the validation in reduced.fit, which is (X_test,Y_test) is not learned, so it gives wronf accuracy in .evalute()
 always give 
val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
This is the code, and the error:

```python
rom keras.datasets import  cifar10
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np

num_train = 50000
num_test = 10000

height, width, depth = 32, 32, 3 # MNIST images are 28x28
num_classes = 10 # there are 10 classes (1 per digit)

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(num_train,height * width * depth)
X_test = X_test.reshape(num_test,height * width*depth)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255 # Normalise data to [0, 1] range
X_test /= 255 # Normalise data to [0, 1] range

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes) # One-hot encode the labels
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes) # One-hot encode the labels

input_img = Input(shape=(height * width * depth,))
s=height * width * depth
x = Dense(s, activation='relu')(input_img)

encoded = Dense(s//2, activation='relu')(x)
encoded = Dense(s//8, activation='relu')(encoded)

y = Dense(s//256, activation='relu')(x)

decoded = Dense(s//8, activation='relu')(y)
decoded = Dense(s//2, activation='relu')(decoded)

z = Dense(s, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)
model = Model(input_img, z)

model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse') # reporting the accuracy

model.fit(X_train, X_train,
      nb_epoch=10,
      batch_size=128,
      shuffle=True,
      validation_data=(X_test, X_test))

mid = Model(input_img, y)
reduced_representation =mid.predict(X_test)


out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(y)
reduced = Model(input_img, out)
reduced.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

reduced.fit(X_train, Y_train,
      nb_epoch=10,
      batch_size=128,
      shuffle=True,
      validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))


scores = reduced.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: ", scores[1])
```

```python
Train on 50000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0639 - val_loss: 0.0633
Epoch 2/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0610 - val_loss: 0.0568
Epoch 3/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0565 - val_loss: 0.0558
Epoch 4/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0557 - val_loss: 0.0545
Epoch 5/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0536 - val_loss: 0.0518
Epoch 6/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0502 - val_loss: 0.0461
Epoch 7/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0443 - val_loss: 0.0412
Epoch 8/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0411 - val_loss: 0.0397
Epoch 9/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0391 - val_loss: 0.0371
Epoch 10/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.0377 - val_loss: 0.0403
Train on 50000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3605 - acc: 0.0977 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 2/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0952 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 3/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0978 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 4/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0980 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 5/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0974 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 6/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.1000 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 7/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 8/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0982 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 9/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0965 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 10/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0978 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
 9856/10000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s('Accuracy: ', 0.10000000000000001)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842931/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-model-2-to-have-shape-none-25 any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple issues with your code.

Your autoencoder is not fully trained, if you plot the training data, you will see the model haven't converged yet. By

```
history = model.fit(X_train, X_train,
nb_epoch=10,
batch_size=128,
shuffle=True,
validation_data=(X_test, X_test))
```

you will obtain the loss values during training. If you plot them, e.g. in matplotlib,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model train vs validation loss 1')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

you will see that it needs more epochs to converge.

The autoencoder architecture is wrongly built, there is typo in line `y = Dense(s//256, activation='relu')(x)`, you probably wanted to use`y = Dense(s//256, activation='linear')(encoded)` so it uses previous layer and not the input. And also you don't want to use the relu activation in latent space, because then it disallows you subtracting latent variables from each other and thus makes the autoencoder much less efficient. 
With those fixes, the model trains withour problems.

I increased number of epochs to 30 for training both networks so it will train better.
At the end of the trainings, the classification model reports `loss: 1.2881 - acc: 0.5397 - val_loss: 1.3841 - val_acc: 0.5126` which is lower than you experienced.